# Asyncio: return output / logging as soon as a coroutine is finished

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to capture the output/log the message of a pool of tasks being executed with asyncio and Python 3.11.

The code below is a simplified abstract of what I have in place, so apologies if it cannot run immediately.
What the full code does is to issue several HTTP requests (made with httpx) to determine the status of the flow to be pursued with a last call to either a PUT or a PUSH.

Below the abstract:

```
async def update(...):
        api_url = '....'
        ret = await self._async_http_request(api_url, Http_Methods.PUT, json_payload)
        
        if ret.status_code >= 400:
            err_msg = ret.json().get('code') or ret.json().get('message')
            return [ret.status_code, err_msg]

        return [ret.status_code, 'Update complete']

async def setup_flow(project_id: str, tasks: list):
    project = await get_project(project_id)
    configs = await get_config_by_projectid(project)
    _collection = await get_collection(project_id)

    name = '_'.join(project['name'], configs['name')

    for x in _collection:
      if x.status == 1:
        # Update
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(update(...), name=x.name))
      else:
        # Add
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(add(...), name=alert.name))


async def main():
    project_ids = [....]
    tasks = []
    for i, p in enumerate(project_ids):
        project_id = project_ids[i]['id']
        await setup_flow(project_id, tasks)

    output = [await asyncio.gather(*tasks)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Both `Add` and `Update` return something that I can capture with the gather above.
E.g.

```
[204, 'Update completed']
```

As I mentioned, I'd love to capture and print/log the status as soon as each task is completed and not to have a big variable with all the output in one pass.
I read something about the loop and the queue, but I'm now getting lost.

What's the best approach? Any snippet/article to put my on the right direction?

---

### UPDATE

Just noticed that by creating two intermediate wrappers as per my example above I can achieve this.
In my code I was having a direct call to a separate class method which was not logging the output but just returning the output.